# Tracking attribute change using custom event

Tags: javascript, dom-events

My problem is that I want to track attribute change on an element using custom event, I have been reading on Mozilla developers, I still don't get it.

So, how does custom events work? and How to use it to track attribute change/variable change (of a class).

Comment: To clarify, what were you reading? [Mutation Observers](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/MutationObserver)?

Comment: I was reading [Creating and trigging events](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/Guide/Events/Creating_and_triggering_events) @colonelsanders

Comment: So how should I bump this? No one know how to do so?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[Standard event listeners](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/Guide/Events/Creating_and_triggering_events) respond to many things, but element attribute changes are not one of them. A [MutationObserver](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/MutationObserver) is really the only way to build something like this yourself, short of a resource-heavy `setInterval` faux-listener.

```
var target = document.querySelector('button');

var observer = new MutationObserver(function(mutations) {
  mutations.forEach(function(mutation) {
    console.log(mutation.attributeName + ' atrribute was changed.');
  });    
});

observer.observe(target, {
  attributes: true
});
```

Here is a [JSFiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/p9u23urs/) where a button click changes an element's color, which is picked up by the MutationObserver.